# How can i listen to a stream and then pass it to Streambuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, stream-builder

Currently I'm listening to a websocket stream in a Streambuilder. When i receive data, I modify the data in the streambuilder itself and pass it to the widget. But since build is called multiple times, the same received data is processed multiple times. So I want to perform processing of data(done in receivedMessage(data)) outside of Streambuilder.So to avoid firing of Streambuilder multiple times, i'm trying to take data processing away from the widget. Is this the right approach, how should i do it?

```
class _DrawingPageState extends State<DrawingPage> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(ipVal);
    _stream = channel.stream;
   }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    child: StreamBuilder(
                          stream: _stream,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if(snapshot.hasData){
                              data = receivedMessage(data);
                              print("Received Message");
                              return Text(data);
                            }
                              else if(snapshot.hasError){
                                print(snapshot.error);
                              }
                            return Text(data);
                          }
                        ),
  }
}
```

Comment: Can i do it using the same stream? I want to listen to the stream in initstate and forward the received stream data to streambuilder.

Comment: you may be able to use [Stream.asBroadcastStream()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asBroadcastStream.html)